# Any way to recover list of open terminal tabs/windows before my system went down unexpectedly?

Tags: terminal

I had been working with maybe 6 tabs open in various directories, when I left for a small vacation. Upon returning, I discover a power outage must have rebooted my machine. Is there any way for me to recover my lost tabs? I'm mostly interested in the directories I was in, but also the history for each tab would be very useful.

EDIT: I am using Scientific Linux (SLC5), and the shell I use is bash.

Comment: While general questions are fine, in this case it would probably be helpful to provide more information such as what terminal emulator and *shell* you were using.  However, I think you are out of luck because I haven't heard of any tabbed terminal emulators that have such session saving.

Comment: I'm using scientific linux (SLC5) and bash. I don't need full session saving, just any way of figuring out what directies I was in prior to the crash.

Comment: `gnome-terminal`?  I still think you are out of luck.  `bash` doesn't handle history across multiple independent concurrent instances very gracefully.  If you had any applications that leave temporary files in the working directory open at the time of the crash searching for those might be one approach.  Otherwise I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: Yeah, gnome-terminal. OK, that's too bad. Thanks!

Comment: You can configure your shell for that (at least zsh, not sure what bash can do). If you haven't, you're pretty much screwed.